# In Jquery Jpanel menu , on mobile, if page length is increasing , menu is opening with a jerkness

Tags: jquery, html

I am using "Jquery Japnel" Menu in a mobile site.
but the problem  is 
 if page length is increasing , menu is opening with a jerkness. 
It is working fine for small length page. but if page having more data like page length in pixel is more than 1000 or 1500 it is opening with a jerkness. as it slide the content.If any one can help then it will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no solution yet.

As far I find out, it can be minimize using some ways.
like:-

There are two main events that jquery jpanel menu provides.

1. BeforeOpen.
2. AfterClose.

These events solved my issues for a limit.

1. You can hide or set display none for page that is non in display area on event BeforeOpen.
2. And unhide in afterClose Event.
   This is pure you logic how do u maintain that.